# Limit search & replace macro to one column on one page

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following Excel macro:

```
Rem Attribute VBA_ModuleType=VBAModule
Sub FixPlatforms()
    Dim fndList As Object
    Set fndList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    fndList.Add "3DO Interactive Multiplayer", "3DO"
    fndList.Add "Nintendo 3DS", "3DS"
    fndList.Add "Ajax", "AJAX"
    fndList.Add "Xerox Alto", "ALTO"
    fndList.Add "Amiga CD32", "AMI32"
    fndList.Add "Amiga", "AMI"
    fndList.Add "Apple I", "APPI"
    fndList.Add "Apple IIe", "APPIIE"
    fndList.Add "Apple IIGS", "APPGS"
    fndList.Add "Apple II Plus", "APPII+"
    fndList.Add "Apple II series", "APPII"
    fndList.Add "Apple II", "APPII"

    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each strKey In fndList.Keys()
        sht.Cells.Replace What:=strKey, Replacement:=fndList(strKey), _
          LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next strKey
    Next sht
End Sub
```

It works fine, but how do I make it so that it only operates on a single column in a single worksheet? (Limiting it to a selection would be okay too, I guess.)

Thanks!

Comment: `Worksheets("specific_worksheet").Columns(4).Replace` would limit the replace to column 4 (i.e. "D") on worksheet "specific_worksheet".  (But why did you add a loop through all the worksheets into your code if you only want to process one worksheet?)

Comment: I don't want to loop any more. Also, how would I do the same with a selection?

Comment: If you don't want to loop, why did you add a loop?  And if you want to do a `Replace` using `Selection`, use `Selection.Replace`.

Comment: Removing the loop would obviously be part of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I make it so that it only operates on a single column

If you only want to operate on a single `Column` in a worksheet and not on all `Cells` in the worksheet, use (for instance) `Columns(4).Replace` instead of `Cells.Replace`.

> in a single worksheet

If you don't want to process all `Worksheets` in the `ActiveWorkbook` and, instead, only want to process (for instance) `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("specific_worksheet")` remove the loop you added to your code to process `Each` worksheet in `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`, and then use `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("specific_worksheet")` instead of your loop object (`sht`).

> Limiting it to a selection would be okay too

If you only want to perform the `Replace` on the current `Selection`, use `Selection.Replace`

Answer (score 1):

Just combining the above comments into an answer (per [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments) meta topic):

```
Sub FixPlatforms()
    Dim fndList As Object
    Set fndList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    fndList.Add "3DO Interactive Multiplayer", "3DO"
    fndList.Add "Nintendo 3DS", "3DS"
    fndList.Add "Ajax", "AJAX"
    fndList.Add "Xerox Alto", "ALTO"
    fndList.Add "Amiga CD32", "AMI32"
    fndList.Add "Amiga", "AMI"
    fndList.Add "Apple I", "APPI"
    fndList.Add "Apple IIe", "APPIIE"
    fndList.Add "Apple IIGS", "APPGS"
    fndList.Add "Apple II Plus", "APPII+"
    fndList.Add "Apple II series", "APPII"
    fndList.Add "Apple II", "APPII"

    For Each strKey In fndList.Keys()
        ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Replace What:=strKey, Replacement:=fndList(strKey), _
          LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next strKey
End Sub
```

Of course, just adjust the Columns(1) to whichever column you want the replace to work in. You can also select a column by using `.EntireColumn` on a Range object like:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").EntireColumn.Replace ...
```

If you just want it to work by Selection, then use the `Selection` object (which is also an object of type Range):

```
Selection.Replace ...
```